# ERROR Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <in JSON at position 0

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have the following JS script:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $("#idSelect").change(function(event) {
        var valor = $(this).val();
        //alert(valor);
        $.post( "ajaxSerie.php", { valorInput: valor }, function( data ) {
            var retorno = JSON.parse(data);
            console.log(retorno);
            $("#pertence").val(retorno['pertence'])// aqui estou atribuindo um input qualquer o valor retornado do php, o input tera o valor de sala206
            $.each(retorno, function() {
                $('<option>').val(retorno['pertence']).text(retorno['pertence']).appendTo('#teste');
            });
        });
    });

}
```

in AJAX looks like this:

```
$idValor = $_POST['valorInput']; 
 $result = [
"pertence" => $idValor
];
echo json_encode($result);
```

when I do local it works perfectly, now when I step to the site on the server the following error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

how to solve this?

Comment: Looks like `ajaxSerie.php` is responding with markup instead of JSON. Look in your browser's _Network_ console to see what it is actually responding with

Answer (score 3):

Your Ajax call might be returning HTML, which begins with a '<', the beginning of the opening HTML tag.

In my experience, Ajax calls returning HTML is a sign that there has been an error in the back end. If you use your browser's developer tools, you'll be able to track your Ajax call and read its response.

Take the time to read that HTML, because most of the time, the error message in the  tag leaves a breadcrumb to find the real problem.

Comment: @Larissasilva what **exactly** is in that _"gigantic html code"_?

Comment: @Larissasilva Now that you've determined this is a *server-side problem*, you should debug that.  As John says, this is really common if you have a 500 Internal Server Error and such.

Comment: has since the doctype, links, meta, script, css, img, has the entire format of a html page

Comment: @Larissasilva, I recommend taking the time to read the html. Most of the time the error message in the BODY offers a breadcrumb.

Answer (score 0):

1st: `$.post(url , {} , callback function(){} , 'json');` you can add `'json'` instead of using `JSON.parse()`

2nd: if your server is running a PHP version older than 5.4

```
$result = [
"pertence" => $idValor
];
```

should be

```
$result = array(
"pertence" => $idValor
);
```

Comment: Adding `'json'` as the data type is a decent idea but it's definitely not going to solve OP's problem. Your second point about PHP array syntax is also incorrect, assuming a [moderately recent version of PHP](http://php.net/manual/migration54.new-features.php) (short array syntax introduced in 5.4 which is 6 years old now)

Comment: `[]` is valid syntax array syntax for PHP these days.  http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: That being said, you may be on to something. If OP's remote host is running PHP < 5.4, their code will error there

Comment: If OP does add `'json'`, they will also have to remove `JSON.parse()`. You should probably point that out in your answer

Comment: thanks @Phil for explanation .. actually I didn't use `JSON.parse()` before I always use this method or ajax type json .. anyway thanks again :)