# VM101:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse (<anonymous>) at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onload (app.js:134)

Tags: javascript

I have some problems with my code in JS. When I want to detect if a person presses the button to eliminate, The console should show me an id with the register, but it shows me that error.

I have looked for a lot of information. For example, some people say that I have problems in my HTML code, but I looked and the code is good.

```
function eliminarContacto(e) {  
    if(e.target.parentElement.classList.contains('btn-borrar')) {  

        const id = e.target.parentElement.getAttribute('data-id'); 
        //console.log(id);

        const respuesta = confirm('Estas seguro?');
        if(respuesta) {


            const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

            xhr.open('GET', `inc/modelos/modelo-contactos.php?id=${id}&accion=borrar`, true);

            xhr.onload = function() {
                if(this.status == 200) {
                    const resultado = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText); 

                    console.log(resultado);
                }
            }
            //enviar la peticion
            xhr.send();
        }  
    }                                                        
 }
```

Comment: The server doesn't respond with JSON but markup/xml.

Comment: Either use the network tab in the developer tools or `console.log(xhr.responseText)` just prior to the `JSON.parse()` - line. You will see the response contains markup (HTML).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ERROR Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <in JSON at position 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53771865/error-uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-in-json-at-position-0)